# Facebook user to user apprequests custom message issue

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-app-requests

I have an app on facebook in sandbox mode.

when i send apprequests (user to user) from this app to my friend with a message(Naturally INVITES)

i don't see my custom message instead i see the notification at the receiving end as

'XXXX send you invite request'

i have tried 'new_style_message' to true indicated by some developer friends but still i can't see my custom message.

please find my code snippet and let me know any changes needed.

```
enter code here
```

FB.ui({
                    method: 'apprequests',
                    message: 'Welcome and meet me',
                    title: 'Request',
                    new_style_message: true,
                    to: _selected_ids

```
            }, callbackhandling);
```

this is my code to send request....but the receiving user is not seeing any custom message.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I send app requests (user to user) from this app to my friend with a message (Naturally Invites) I don't see my custom message. Instead I see the notification at the receiving end as
>
> XXXX send you invite request

That’s how invites are **supposed** to work – it’s in the requests docs.

> I have tried *new_style_message* to true indicated by some developer friends but still I can't see my custom message.

That doesn’t work any more.

Comment: @CBore so is there any other way so that i can send my invite so that the receiver can see my message in his notification. the above 'new_style_message' is working for apps in sandbox mode and when sending the request from developer accounts related facebook accounts.